# Get a table value from web

Tags: excel, vba, web

I am trying to get the AE name "Jack_Ma" from our internel web by excel VBA, but always failed when processing this code"

```
AE = .document.getElementById("table_result").contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("AE")(0).innerText"
```

> error"Run-time error '424', Object required".

Anyone can help figure out what the problem is?
Below is my vba code and HTML source code. I've hidden the real web address because it is for internal use and cannot be accessed from internet:

VBA Code:

```
    Sub IE_K2()

        Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
        Dim myButton As Object
        Dim AE As String
        Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
        With appIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.test.com"
        Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
        Loop
        .document.getElementById("box_search").Value = "7ZPABF3"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        Set myButton = .document.getElementById("btn_search")
        myButton.Click
        
        Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
        Loop
          
        AE = .document.getElementById("table_result").contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("AE") 
        (0).innerText
        MsgBox AE
        End With
        Set appIE = Nothing
        Set myButton = Nothing
    End Sub
```

HTML source code:

```
        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped" 
        width="100%" id="table_result">
        <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>Svctag</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>ShipDate</th>
                <th>Warranty Max</th>
                <th>StopDate</th>
                <th>Current</th>
                <th>Account</th>
                <th>Contract</th>
                <th>Pfofile</th>
                <th>Segment</th>
                <th>Province</th>
                <th>AE</th>
                <th>ISR</th>
                <th>SAM</th>
        </tr>

     </thead>
     <tbody>
            <tr>
                        <td>7ZPABF3</td>
                        <td>Model 1000</td>
                        <td>2021-07-19</td>
                        <td>PTP</td>
                        <td>2026-07-21</td>
                        <td>PSP</td>
                        <td>NextGen Company</td>
                        <td>Goldlevel</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>TW MB R&amp;D</td>
                        <td>Asia</td>
                        <td>Jack_Ma</td>
                        <td>Rainny_Liu</td>
                        <td>Thomson_Chen</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I see nothing in the HTML that has a class called `AE`

Comment: @braX So how to correct this line to get the "Jack_Ma" value?

Comment: Can try something like `.document.getElementById("table_result").getElementsByTagName("td")(11).innerText`.

Comment: @RaymondWu still report this error "Object required".

Comment: @HL086 Try setting to a variable first instead of chaining the method. e.g. `Set tableEle = .document.getElementById("table_result")` then `AE = tableEle.getElementsByTagName("td")(11).innerText`.

Comment: @RaymondWu I tried this but the same error "Object required".

Comment: Can you try adding the line `Debug.Print .document.getElementById("table_result") Is Nothing` and see the output in the Immediate Window? If it's `True` then that element is not found.

Comment: @RaymondWu report the same error "Object required"

Comment: Try `Dim htmlDoc as HTMLDocument: Set htmlDoc = appIE.Document` then `Debug.Print htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result") Is Nothing` again. You need to add `Microsoft HTML Object Library` to your reference. @HL086

Comment: @RaymondWu This time no error is reported and print "True" in immediate window. What should I do next?

Comment: @HL086 This means that element doesn't exist. The table probably need some time to load so what you can try now is do a `While` loop to wait for the table to load so maybe something like `Do While htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result") Is Nothing: DoEvents: Set htmlDoc = appIE.document : Loop` beware that it could lead to infinite looping..

Comment: There are two possibilities why the table is not found. 1. it is not loaded yet, as Raymond said. 2. it is in an iFrame. Then the document of the iFrame must be accessed explicitly. Apart from that, IE should not be used anymore, because it is finally EOL. The real URL would help.

Comment: @RaymondWu Many thanks for your help and patience! As you said, this table needs some time to load. It has been fixed by following your solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The table that you are looking for is loaded dynamically and so it needs some time to load after the webpage is loaded.

1 possible method to handle this is to make `While` loop to check for existence of the element and `DoEvents` in the loop:

```
Do While htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result") Is Nothing
   DoEvent
   Set htmlDoc = appIE.document
Loop
```

Note: This can potentially cause infinite looping if the webpage is not loading the table for some reason so you need to account of that situation.